# I am trying to load more than one google map on a website given an address. The last map is the only one shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to take an N number of addresses and be able to display those addresses on N number of Google maps. I have an N number of div elements with the class attribute set to "canvas". When I run my code the last table cell element contains a map of the location I need. None of the other table cells contain a map.

JavaScript:

```
// JavaScript Document

var geocoder;
var mapOptions;
var newLocation;
var element;

$(document).ready(function()
{

    $.each($(".canvas"),function(i,value)
    {   
        element = value;
        initialize($("tr").eq(i).children("td").text());
    });
});

function initialize(tr) 
{
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
codeAddress(tr);

}

function codeAddress(address) 
{       
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            newLocation = results[0].geometry.location;
            mapOptions = 
            {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(newLocation.Ya,newLocation.Za),
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions);

        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
  <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
         <table>
             <tr>
                  <td>Address 1</td><td class="canvas"></td>
                  <td>Address 2</td><td class="canvas"></td>
                  <td>Address 3</td><td class="canvas"></td>
                  <td>Address 4</td><td class="canvas"></td>
                  <td>Address 5</td><td class="canvas"></td>
                  <td>Address 6</td><td class="canvas"></td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The html elements you are trying to select in jQuery aren't in the example.

Comment: Where is the code You draw these maps to the View?
But I think the reason may be:

     var geocoder; 

This is an Reference type.
You should :

    function initialize(tr) 
    {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();    
    }

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite `element` in each loop of `$.each()`  .

Pass it as argument to `codeAddress` instead:

```
$.each($(".canvas"),function(i,element)
    {   
        initialize($(element).prev().text(),element);
    });
```

.....

```
function codeAddress(address,element){
  //your code
}
```